# Web scraping returning empty dictionary

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors

I'm trying to scrape all the data from this website `https://ricetta.it/ricette-secondi` using *Python-Selenium*.

I'd like to put them into a dictionary, as seen from the code below.
However, this is just returning an empty list back.

```py
import pprint
detail_recipes = []
for recipe in list_recipes:
  title = ""
  description = ""
  ingredient = ""
  if(len(recipe.find_elements_by_css_selector(".post-title")) > 0):
    title = recipe.find_elements_by_css_selector(".post-title")[0].text
  if(len(recipe.find_elements_by_css_selector(".post-excerpt")) > 0):
    description = recipe.find_elements_by_css_selector(".post-excerpt")[0].text
  if(len(recipe.find_elements_by_css_selector(".nm-ingr")) > 0):
    ingredient = recipe.find_elements_by_css_selector(".nm-ingr")[0].text

  detail_recipes.append({'title': title,
                        'description': description,
                        'ingredient': ingredient
                        })

len(detail_recipes)
pprint.pprint(detail_recipes[0:10])
```

Comment: is your problem solved by [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68522832/12446721)? I have gave you some little more information about those library, if you aren't familiar with that library then what would be very helpful. If it is solved then don't forget to mark this as accepted answer. If any queries ask in comment.

Comment: Thank you, your code is perfect. But I can't save the data in a CSV file. In fact when I write: df.to_csv("<filename.csv>") I obtain: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Comment: You forget to write `df=pd.DataFrame(df)

df.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
` two line :)

Comment: Thank you really much! Last thing: I'd also like to scrape the link of each title. How can i get them?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check that. And if you like my effort, give upvote to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import requests
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

url="https://ricetta.it/ricette-secondi"

page=requests.get(url)
soup=bs(page.content,'lxml')

df={'title': [],'description': [],'ingredient':[]}

for div in soup.find_all("div",class_="post-bordered"):
    df["title"].append(div.find(class_="post-title").text)
    try:
        df["description"].append(div.find(class_="post-excerpt").text)
    except:
        df["description"].append(np.nan)
    i=div.find_all(class_="nm-ingr")
    if len(i)>0:
        df["ingredient"].append([j.text for j in i])
    else:
        df["ingredient"].append(np.nan)

df=pd.DataFrame(df)

df.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                               title  ...                                         ingredient
0       Polpette di pane e formaggio  ...  [uovo, pane, pangrattato, parmigiano, latte, s...
1     Torta 7 vasetti alle melanzane  ...  [uovo, olio, latte, yogurt, farina 00, fecola ...
2  Torta a sole con zucchine e speck  ...  [pasta sfoglia, zucchina, ricotta, uovo, speck...
3                    Pesto di limoni  ...  [limone, pinoli, parmigiano, basilico, prezzem...
4                    Bombe di patate  ...  [patata, farina 00, uovo, parmigiano, sale e p...
5             Polpettone di zucchine  ...  [zucchina, uovo, parmigiano, pangrattato, pros...
6                  Insalata di pollo  ...  [petto di pollo, zucchina, pomodorino, insalat...
7                      Club sandwich  ...  [pane, petto di pollo, pomodoro, lattuga, maio...
8                Crostata di verdure  ...  [farina 00, burro, acqua, sale, zucchina, pomo...
9              Pesto di barbabietola  ...  [barbabietola, parmigiano, pinoli, olio, sale,...

[10 rows x 3 columns]
```

I don't know if you use these library or not, but that website doesn't uses javascript to load data, so we can scrape that website using `requests` and `bs4`. Most of the people prefer to use these library, if website doesn't uses javascript to load data. It is easy and faster then selenium. And for showing/displaying data I am using `pandas` with is also preferable library for working on table like data. It exactly print data in table like structure and you can save that scraped data in `csv`, `excel file` also.
If you want to scrape all of the data from next page also then try this:

```
df={'title': [],'description': [],'ingredient':[]}

for i in range(0,108):
    url=f"https://ricetta.it/ricette-secondi?page={i}"
    page=requests.get(url)
    soup=bs(page.content,'lxml')

    for div in soup.find_all("div",class_="post-bordered"):
        df["title"].append(div.find(class_="post-title").text)
        try:
            df["description"].append(div.find(class_="post-excerpt").text)
        except:
            df["description"].append(np.nan)
        i=div.find_all(class_="nm-ingr")
        if len(i)>0:
            df["ingredient"].append([j.text for j in i])
        else:
            df["ingredient"].append(np.nan)
```

It will scrape all of the 107 pages of data from that website.

You can save this `df` to `csv` or `excel file` by using :

```
df.to_csv("<filename.csv>")
# or for excel:
df.to_excel("<filename.xlsx>")
```

**Edit :**
As you ask you want to scrape, link of all recipes, I have figure out two things, first just replace space of titles by `-` and that is the link for that recipe and another is scrape link from there, for that you can use this piece of code:

```
div.find(class_="post-title")["href"]
```

It will return the link of that recipe. And for another approach you can do this:

```
df["links"]=df["title"].apply(lambda x: "https://ricetta.it/"+x.replace(" ","-").lower())
#.lower() is just to not make like a random text but it you remove it also it works.
```

But I personally suggest you just to scrape link from website cuz while making link own our own we may made mistakes.